# Showing description of value map in print layout in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis

How can I show the description of a value map (joined layer) in a print layout in QGIS (QGIS 3.4.15 or 3.10.6). It just shows the value...

Data is Geopackage, point layer joined with table (no geometry). I select the values in the form with a value map (value and description, both with different entries). In the form and the attribute table QGIS shows the description as it should be. In the print layout (using atlas) it shows the description as well, but if I use a joined field it just shows the value, not the description.

[image: This is a value map. I want to show the description in a joined field in a atlas layout, not the value.]

Comment: Please describe more detailed what you're trying to achieve, maybe provide a screenshot of your current layout and an example of your goal. Furthermore please add a description of your data, if it is a WMS, a raster file, a shape file, how it is styled etc.

Comment: Sorry, here are more details. Data is Geopackage, point layer joined with table (no geometry). I select the values in the form with a value map (value and description, both with different entries). In the form and the attribute table QGIS shows the description as it should be. In the print layout (using atlas) it shows the description as well, but if I use a joined field it just shows the value, not the description.

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/363772/edit) your question accordingly, picking relevant information from comments is a nuissance. Also, without an image I have no idea what you mean by "value map".

Comment: I think he explained clearly and I am having the same issue. I would like some advices how to do it. I am importing an attribute table to ATLAS and I just see the values from the value map but i would like to have the Description. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a very late answer, but here's how to do what I think you were trying to do. Basically, you need to use the **represent_value** function. In the main properties of your composer layout attribute table:

- Go to **Attributes**
- Select the field for which you want the description shown
- Click on the **ε** button next to the attribute name to compose an expression
- From the **Record and Attributes** functions section, add **represent_value** to your expression with the required field as an argument
- Click **OK** to go back to the attributes setup and click **OK** again

The description should now be shown instead of the raw value.

[image]